# рендер <div>{routes} </div> в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два файла на реакте
1:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinksPage } from "./pages/LinksPage";
import { CreatePage } from "./pages/CreatePage";
import { DetailPage } from "./pages/DetailPage";
import { AuthPage } from "./pages/AuthPage";

export const useRoutes = (isAuthenticated) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/links" element={LinksPage}>
          <LinksPage />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/create" element={CreatePage}>
          <CreatePage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/detail/:id" element={DetailPage}>
          <DetailPage />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/auth" element={AuthPage}>
        <AuthPage />
      </Route>
      <Navigate to="/" />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

и второй :

```js
import React from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "./routes";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "materialize-css";

function App() {
  const routes = useRoutes;
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">{routes}</div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Компилируется без ошибок однако элемент

```
   <div className="container">{routes}</div>
```

не рендерится

для примера что лежит в элементе authpage

```js
import React from "react";

export const AuthPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> AuthPage</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Помогите понять почему так происходит. заранее благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Возможно причина в том что в указанной ниже строке хук (который является функцией) не вызывается (у него нет `()` после названия, и соответственно в переменную `routes` попадает тело функции вместо ее результата).

```
const routes = useRoutes;
```

Comment: Поправил с учетом вашего комментария

Comment: Cпс попробую с ()

Answer (score 0):

Он не рендерится, потому что вы пытаетесь отобразить его, как переменную javascript, но `routes`, которую вы используете является react компонентом, чтобы его использовать, его имя надо поменять на `Routes`, иначе реакт будет думать, что routes - это html тег. Сделайте вот так:

```
import React from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "./routes";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "materialize-css";

function App() {
  const Routes = useRoutes;
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Routes />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

А чтобы было еще проще, вы можете использовать useRoutes, как реакт компонент, потому что, use... обычно обозначают какой-то hook, но useRoutes является компонентом, поэтому нет смысла давать ему такое имя, импортируйте сразу компоненту AppRoutes

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinksPage } from "./pages/LinksPage";
import { CreatePage } from "./pages/CreatePage";
import { DetailPage } from "./pages/DetailPage";
import { AuthPage } from "./pages/AuthPage";

export const AppRoutes = ({isAuthenticated}) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/links" element={LinksPage}>
          <LinksPage />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/create" element={CreatePage}>
          <CreatePage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/detail/:id" element={DetailPage}>
          <DetailPage />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/auth" element={AuthPage}>
        <AuthPage />
      </Route>
      <Navigate to="/" />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

App

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRoutes } from "./AppRoutes";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "materialize-css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <AppRoutes />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: все равно возникает проблема именно в этом блоке :
```
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <AppRoutes />
      </div>
    </Router>
```
если убрать все написать внутрь дива просто какой то текст - все окей, но почему то динамично не подгружает то что лежит в pages